# $\sup_{t \in I}\{kf(t)\}=k\sup_{t \in I}\{f(t)\}?$

Tags: real-analysis

If $k\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, is it true that:

$$\sup_{t \in I}\{kf(t)\}=k\sup_{t \in I}\{f(t)\}?$$

If so, how can this be proved?

Comment: True if $k\ge 0$, false otherwise.

Comment: Coming to a proof, let $M := \sup f$ and $M’ := \sup kf $ with $k>0$ (if $k=0$ there’s nothing to prove); you have to prove that $M’ = k M$, i.e. that $k M$ satisfies the properties of the supremum for the function $kf(t)$… Try writing down a sketch of a proof. ;-)